# Titanium [ERROR] JDK version 1.7.0_03 detected, but 1.6 is required

Tags: android, titanium, java

I try to run a simple "hello world" mobile appliction with the titanium android emulator, but I get the following errors:

> [ERROR] JDK version 1.7.0_03 detected, but 1.6 is required
>
> ERROR: The process "2196" not found.

I have downloaded and installed the JDK 1.6, but it still happens. Do you know what I need to do?

p.s.: I can see the emulator running, but I can't see my application in the applications list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently and unfortunately, for a system with both JDK-6 and JDK-7 installed, only the JDK-6 path may appear on the system `PATH`.

The usual way to do that is to:

1. Define an environment variable `JAVA_HOME=G:\Program Files\java\jdk1.6.0_24`
2. Add/Set `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` in your `PATH` variable

---

I've tried different things to convince the Titanium Studio to use a JDK differently from the one defined for the system, but all i came up with is this, changing the system path to the JDK-6.

Don't forget to restart the Titanium Studio/Eclipse after having changed the environment variables.